# Dynamically Add Searchable Items to Table to submit for form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to build an interface to allow quick association of items.  We have three classes:

```
public class Service{
  public int ServiceId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<ProductUse> ProductsUsed {get;set;}
  ...
}

public class Product{
  public int ProductId {get;set;}
  public string ProductName {get;set;}
  ...
}

public class ProductUse{
  public int ProductUseId {get;set;}
  public Product ProductToUse {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("ProductToUse")]
  public int ProductId {get;set;}
  public Service ServiceUsesProduct {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("ServiceUsesProduct")]
  public int ServiceId {get;set;}
  public double AmountOfProduct {get;set;}
}
```

We have already pre-populated product with 1000s of product.  My goal was to create an interface for Create Service that allows dynamically adding products to service.  I can do it one at a time, but this seems inordinately slow.

I was hoping to be able to create a table on the create service razor that could do something like this:

```
Search For Product: <input type="search">
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th> Product ID</th>
        <th> Product Name </th>
        <th> Amount Used </th>
        <th> Remove From List</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ProductUse #1 details
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ProductUse #2 details
        </tr>
        .....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

such that when an item is searched and selected it is added to the table with the appropriate fields from `ProductUse`.  Then when the service is submitted, it creates the service and links the product used to services.

I know how to do it one by one AFTER creating the service, but is it possible to do it at the same time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean can you do bulk insert? Yes, you can. I think you are looking for [a model binding to collection](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: It is more the UI component how to add models through the web-page to then add that link.  I couldn't figure out how to create the UI to allow that.